# Insert Error while trying to load data to postgres from oracle using Kafka-Connect-API

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm trying to transfer data from oracle to postgres using kafka jdbc connect API

I don't wanna create a new table at postgres automatically. so I created my own table at postgres before creating a connectors.

so these are my configuration:-

Source:-(Ora XE 11g)

```
curl -i -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/ora_1/config
    -H "Content-Type: application/json"
    -d '{ 
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector", 
        "connection.url":"jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/db", 
        "connection.user":"user", 
        "connection.password":"passwd", 
        "mode":"incrementing", 
        "incrementing.column.name": "<column_name>", 
        "topic.prefix":"ora_", 
        "table.whitelist":"<table_name>", 
        "poll.interval.ms":10000 
        }'
```

Target:- (Postgres)

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/pg_1/config \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "connection.url":"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db",
        "connection.user":"user",
        "connection.password":"passwd",
        "tasks.max" : "1",
        "topics":"<topic_name>",
        "insert.mode":"insert",
        "table.name.format":"<table_name>"
    }'
```

[If we see in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHvHi.jpg)
In insert statement the columns are coming within the double quotes which is leading me to an insert error. When I tried by creating the table with columns enclosing in double quotes at postgres then it's working fine.

So, Anyone can please help me out how to avoid those double quotes for those columns as I don't wanna create table automatically and don't wanna create table by defining it's columns in double quotes.....

Comment: Could you please add code blocks to make your code more readable? [see here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) on how to make code blocks

Comment: Okay @EkadhSingh. Now it is much clear to read I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `"quote.sql.identifiers":"never"` at the source and sink configuration. now it is working fine.

you can have a look here:-
https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/455